# ActiveRecord is resetting all my previously defined variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm building a rake task in order to migrate some data between two databases. The ones have exactly the same structure. My task is so:

```
namespace :oab_nexus_migration do
  task :start, [:oab_user, :nexus_user] => :environment do |t, args|
    oab_account      = User.find_by_username(args[:oab_user]).main_account

    oab_trials       = oab_account.trials.includes(:parts)
    oab_schedules    = oab_account.schedules
    oab_movements    = oab_account.movements
    oab_annotations  = oab_account.annotations
    oab_hearings     = oab_account.hearings
    oab_publications = oab_account.publications
    oab_tasks        = oab_account.tasks
    oab_people       = oab_account.people.includes(:addresses, :internet_addresses, :phones)

    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:other_database)

    ...
    More code here
  end
end
```

The task is executed with:

`RAILS_ENV=production rake oab_nexus_migration:start[user_one, user_two]`

After retrieve all information I need from database one, I need to insert it into database two. But something really weird is happening. If I, for example, call `p oab_trials` (or any other variable) before `establish_connection`, all values are there, represented by a large array. But if I try to call it after `establish_connection`, the returned value is an empty array. Seems like ActiveRecord is resetting all my previously defined variables.

What is happening here?

Comment: You might want to make two different but similar models to port data over, one for each database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The related collections that you are referencing are lazy-evaluated instances of `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Lazy-evaluation doesn't work if your database connection changes mid-stream.

You need to eager load these relations into memory first, before switching connections. Call `.to_a` on the relations to force this.

```
oab_account      = User.find_by_username(args[:oab_user]).main_account

oab_trials       = oab_account.trials.includes(:parts).to_a
oab_schedules    = oab_account.schedules.to_a
oab_movements    = oab_account.movements.to_a
oab_annotations  = oab_account.annotations.to_a
oab_hearings     = oab_account.hearings.to_a
oab_publications = oab_account.publications.to_a
oab_tasks        = oab_account.tasks.to_a
oab_people       = oab_account.people.includes(:addresses, :internet_addresses, :phones).to_a
```

Answer (score 2):

`oab_account.trials.includes(:parts)` doesn't store a value, it stores a reference to an `ActiveRecord::Relation` that is lazily evaluated.

So it's not that `ActiveRecord` is resetting the value of the variable, rather, when you connect to your second database you're changing the reference to an empty collection.